# Translate array inside controller using pascal translate in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, translation

I'm having some trouble figuring out how i could translate my array inside the controller.

Inside my controller i did something like this :

```
    var vm = this;

    $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function () {
        vm.salutation = $translate.instant('client.test');
        console.log(vm.salutation);
    });

    vm.test = 'test';


    vm.servicesData = {
        listOfServiceNames : [
            "sample",
            vm.salutation,
            vm.test,

        ]
    }
```

Inside the view:

```
 <bootstrap-dropdown ng-model="vm.client.salutation"  data-placeholder="Aanhef" data-dropdown-data="vm.servicesData.listOfServiceNames"></bootstrap-dropdown>
```

The console.log shows the correct string. But when i look at the front end `vm.salutation` is empty. Any clues how i could correctly use translation here ?

Comment: Did you try initializing `vm.salutation` to something first in the controller? If you did already, can you show how your view looks like? A plunker would help as well

Comment: Hi @NMittal i did initializing  vm.salutation but the dropdown still gives an empty string. But console.log shows the correct string.

Comment: I guess you need to have `vm.servicesData.push(vm.salutation)` in your $on callback and `vm.servicesData = {
        listOfServiceNames : [
            "sample",
            vm.test
        ]
    }`

Comment: @NMittal   vm.servicesData.listOfServiceNames.push(vm.salutation); did the trick. If you want you can create an answer of this. I gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, You should push items to the `listOfServiceNames` array for the watchers to trigger and update the view.

You need

```
 $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function () {
        vm.salutation = $translate.instant('client.test');
        vm.servicesData.push(vm.salutation);        
        console.log(vm.salutation);
  });
```

And

```
vm.servicesData = {
    listOfServiceNames : [
        "sample",
         vm.test
    ]
}
```